# Why is my Web Worker terminated?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a handle on web workers when I came across a very peculior behaviour. For some reason it's terminated after a few seconds, even though I have code in it that's running.

Here's my code;

Main JavaScript-file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var worker = new Worker("js/TestWorker.js");
    worker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
        console.log(event.data);
    });

    worker.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    });
});
```

Worker file:

```
(function () {
    var updateCounter = 0;

    var updater = function () {
        updateCounter += 1;
        console.log("Update counter: " + updateCounter);

        postMessage("test");
        setTimeout(updater, 10000);
    };

    updater();
})();
```

As stated, the worker just stops functioning after a few seconds, 10-20seconds or so.

But if I add this piece of code to my main JavaScript-file;

```
var check = function () {
    var localWorker = worker;
    // setTimeout(check, 1000);
};

// setTimeout(check, 1000);
```

The worker works as intended. The setTimeout-calls aren't needed either, hence why they're commented out. (Note that I can just aswell replace the assignment with *worker.length* or something similar and it will still work just fine.

Can someone explain this behaviour? Is the worker getting terminated and (erroneously) garbage-collected by the browser or is something else happening here that I'm missing?

Worth to note is that my browser (Chrome) isn't outputing any errors or warnings to the console either.

**EDIT:** The same behaviour is observed whether the code is executed inside an anonymous function or not.

**EDIT2:** If I place the worker variable in the global scope it does not get terminated prematurely. What might be the reason for this?

Comment: Very curious. I was under the impression that web workers are similar to DOM nodes in that they can only be killed explicitly (i.e. they shouldn't be simply going out-of-scope / garbage collected, especially since you've added some listeners). Have you tried the same code in FireFox, etc.? It sounds to me like a bug.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, just tested in Firefox, works as it should.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some research shows that while web workers are supposed to function as you expect (i.e. won't be perceptibly garbage collected), there are some known issues in Chrome which mean you can't rely on that behaviour.

Of specific interest would be this very similar bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=572225 which in turn references a more underlying bug: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=572226

It seems to be due to an attempt to garbage collect workers which cannot possibly perform any future activities (in which case the garbage collection would be undetectable, as it's supposed to be), but a flaw in the logic for detecting this state means that any pending activities which aren't directly related to responding to an incoming message will be ignored.

Basically, while you *should* be able to assume web-workers behave like DOM nodes which can only be removed explicitly, in practice (for now) you need to make sure you always keep a reference to the worker accessible from somewhere, otherwise when the garbage collector kicks in it may kill the worker. This is only necessary if you're using setTimeout or similar in the worker; if it just responds to messages, you won't have a problem.

Comment: Ah, I see, interesting!

Answer (score 2):

Maybe worker var must be global

```
var worker;  

$(document).ready(function () { 
    worker = new Worker("js/TestWorker.js");     
    worker.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
            console.log(event.data);
    });

    worker.addEventListener('error', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Yeah, there seems to be something to this. The worker remains if I place the variable in the global scope. Any ideas why this is?

Comment: I think that worker variables are garbage collected like any other variable and when anonymous function ends all the local variables are garbage collected.

Comment: Hmm, no, I don't think so. If that was the case I would have encountered this problem on many more occasions, variables vanishing and loosing their values etc.

Comment: Ok, I was wrong. I'm testing it in fiddle and the worker isn't garbage collected if it's a local variable, it's running forever (without your last piece of code) in firefox and chrome https://jsfiddle.net/meji/s8umLu1e/

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
 ... 
})();
```

This is a anonymous function which will be called once after definition and after that the browser throws it away.
Your web worker is defined it that scope and that's why it's only working for a short period of time.

Comment: No, that can't be it. I get the same behaviour if the code is executed in the global scope.